¿Cuándo usar la palabra "cirugía" vs "operación?"
Una búsqueda breve sugiere que "cirugía" es más especifica, y "operación" más amplia. Al uso común, ¿importa si digo, "mi hermano tiene una operación del pie la semana que viene" o "mi hermano tiene una cirugía del pie la semana que viene"?

No interesa la distincción, se puede decir de ambas maneras. Las dos son usadas y se entienden claramente en el lenguaje corriente,
Decir que (la semana que viene, tu hermano)

tiene una operación del pie

es equivalente a decir que

tiene una cirugía del pie

implicando, con cualquiera de ellas, que tendrá una intervención médica en esa parte del cuerpo
Una consulta al diccionario RAE muestra que son sinónimas

cirugía
2. f. Operación quirúrgica.
Sin.:   operación, intervención.

